# cannot upload csv file on nodejs server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, csv, fast-csv

I am trying to upload a csv file through *react* at frontend & *node.js* server and store it in an array. I have used *fast csv* module to parse this csv file but *fast csv* module is asking for a buffer or url . My react is sending me an blank object. I am badly stuck , please help me out of it. I am counting on you .

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const [company, setCompany] = React.useState('');
const [city, setcity] = React.useState("");
const [file, setFile] = React.useState("");
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

let csvData = new FormData();
csvData.append("file", file);


const handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/csv',  { csvData } );
        console.log(res);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};

 <input className={classes.input} id="contained-button-file" multiple type="file" 
         onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])} />

                    <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">

                        <Button variant="contained" color="primary"
                        component="span" startIcon={<CloudUpload />}>
                            Upload Data
                        </Button>

                    </label>
```

**UPDATE**:

updated backend code from responses provided so that I can get help on front end code now.

After updating code get error from backend.

error:`TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`

My backend code goes in this way:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import multer from 'multer';
const upload = multer({ dest: '/tmp/csv/' });
const csv = require('fast-csv');

router.post('/csv', upload.single('file'), (req, res, next) => {
let filerows = [];

let stream = fs.createReadStream(req.file.path);

stream.pipe(
    // csv.fromPath(req.file.path)
    csv
        .parse()
        .on('data', (data) => {
            filerows.push(data);
        })
        .on('error', () => {
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Failed to upload' });
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            // console.log(filerows);
            
            const sql =
            'INSERT INTO bikes_database(website, company_name, category,city, brand_name, bike_name, bike_url, hour_rent, weekday_rent, weekend_rent, 7_days_rent, 15_days_rent, 30_days_rent, gst, convinence_fee,booking_confirmation, helmet,deposit, km_limit, speed_limit, home_delivery, product_page) VALUES ?';
            
            db.query(sql, [filerows], (err, result) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.json("uploaded successfully")
            });

            fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path);
        })
);
```

});

Comment: Please put text in your post, _as text_. Don't use screenshots. Remember to read through [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and update your post accordingly.

Comment: Please see [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) which explains why it's important to post code, errors, etc. as formatted text instead of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the multer middleware to provide path location for the file. Without it path may be undefined which is probs what's causing your error

```
  const fs = require('fs');
  const multer = require('multer');
  const upload = multer({ dest: 'tmp/csv/' });
  const csv = require('fast-csv');

  router.post('/csv', upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {
    const fileRows = [];

    // open uploaded file
    csv.fromPath(req.file.path)
      .on("data", function (data) {
        fileRows.push(data); // push each row
      })
      .on("error", function () {
          res.status(500).json({
              message: "Failed to upload file"
          });
      })
      .on("end", function () {
        console.log(fileRows)
        fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path);   // remove temp file
        
        //process "fileRows" and respond
        
         res.json({
            message: "Upload Completed!"
         });
      })
  }));
```

As for your react code, I can see that you’re setting any elements with the text returned from request. Inside handle submit you will need to set the text from the response received. Something like this but you also need to handle setting the error message if that’s received instead

```
     this.setState({
         text: response.data.message 
     });
```

Comment: That’s great!! Glad to hear it

Comment: Edward there is some issues with my frontend also pls help me out and check the question again. thnx

Comment: There’s nothing different in the description. Probs be better to post a second question and provide the code and error you see in text format.

Comment: Could you copy the code and the error in text format instead of pictures. For both questions asked. Thank you

Comment: please review the code Edward & pardon for wasting your precious time. Hope you understand i am a beginner.‍♂️

Comment: Oh, I see you copied the backend code from the response in your description. You don’t normally want to do that because future users may think answer was copied from question but it was the other way around. Will take a look at your front end and let you now

Comment: No worries, we are all hear to learn. Updated answer

Comment: i am using funtional component . please suggest something from react hooks. updated question

Answer (score 0):

for backend my updated code works fine:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import multer from 'multer';
const upload = multer({ dest: '/tmp/csv/' });
const csv = require('fast-csv');

router.post('/csv', upload.single('file'), (req, res, next) => {
let filerows = [];

let stream = fs.createReadStream(req.file.path);

stream.pipe(
// csv.fromPath(req.file.path)
csv
    .parse()
    .on('data', (data) => {
        filerows.push(data);
    })
    .on('error', () => {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Failed to upload' });
    })
    .on('end', () => {
        // console.log(filerows);
        
        const sql =
        'INSERT INTO bikes_database(website, company_name, category,city, brand_name, 
   bike_name, bike_url, hour_rent, weekday_rent, weekend_rent, 7_days_rent, 
   15_days_rent, 30_days_rent, gst, convinence_fee,booking_confirmation, 
   helmet,deposit, km_limit, speed_limit, home_delivery, product_page) VALUES ?';
        
        db.query(sql, [filerows], (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json("uploaded successfully")
        });

        fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path);
    })
  );
```

For Frontend we have:

```
 import React from 'react';
 import axios from 'axios';

const [company, setCompany] = React.useState('');
const [city, setcity] = React.useState("");
const [file, setFile] = React.useState("");
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

let csvData = new FormData();
csvData.append("file", file);


const handleSubmit = async () => {
try {
    const res = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost:5000/csv',
            data: csvData,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
        });
    console.log(res);
} 
catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
 };

 <input className={classes.input} id="contained-button-file" multiple type="file" 
     onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])} />

                <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">

                    <Button variant="contained" color="primary"
                    component="span" startIcon={<CloudUpload />}>
                        Upload Data
                    </Button>

                </label>
```